# want to use visual studio dll into android app

Tags: c#, android

I made one android app which use "asmx" web service and get Output.

I made Webservice for only use dll of Visual studio. Is there any way to not use webservice and directly use dll into android application. Please help me

Comment: No, you cant use dll instead of webservice.

Comment: Have you seen Xamarin.com ?

Comment: L look into Xamarin.android and i learn it and start develop app into that, I develop app for LED but i don't know how to add dll into it, please tell me

Comment: Where i have to put dll in the application

Comment: because it gives me Dll not found Exception